# linq.dynamic.core join resultSelector InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, linq, join, dynamic

I'm trying to join two DataRow Collections on a dynamic Field.
This is the query.

```
string strKeyField="Campaign";
var result = dataRows1.Join(dataRows2,
                           "new(it[strKeyField] as Key)",
                           "new(it[strKeyField] as Key)",
                           "new(outer as outTable, inner as innTable)");
```

But I get the below error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast Object of type
>   'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`1[System.Data.DataRow]]'
>   to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Data.DataRow]'.

Comment: Can you post structure of `DataRow1` and `DataRow2`

Comment: IQueryable<DataRow> dataRows1= dsGroupValues.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().AsQueryable();
                        IQueryable<DataRow> dataRows2 = dsGroupValues1.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().AsQueryable();

Comment: `var res = (from r1 in dRows  join r2 in d1Rows`
                  `on (string)r1["field"] equals (string)r2["Column"]`
                  `select new { r1, r2 });` does this help?

Comment: The problem is that the number of key fields may vary, so I need Dynamic Linq Join. I'm trying with only 1 field. When I find the solution, I will add the others.